# Can anyone help me identify the error in my last function?

Tags: arrays, c, function

i have written this program  (its not finished, there are more functions to be added) however, I want to know why my withinBudget function is sometimes producing correct results and other times producing inaccurate results. The withinBudget works out whether or not the customer has sufficient balance or not. if it returns true it prints purchase has been successful or prints insufficient balance.

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int isItemExist(char itemPrefixes[], char itemPrefix);
void displayMenu(char itemPrefixes[], int itemPrices[], int n);
int withinBudget(int budget, char itemPurchased, char itemPrefixes[], int itemPrices[]);


int n;


int main() {

char itemPrefixes[5];
int itemPrices[5];
int budget = 0;
char itemPurchased;

printf("***ItemPrefixes***");
printf("\nA: Apple\n");
printf("O: Orange\n");
printf("M: Mango\n");
printf("P: Pear\n");
printf("G: Grapes\n");

printf("\n***ShopKeeperPanel***");
printf("\nHow many fruit items do you want to add to the shop?: ");
scanf_s("%d", &n);

int chosenFruitItem = 0;
while (chosenFruitItem < n) {

printf("\n(%d) Enter the item prefix: ", chosenFruitItem + 1);
char itemPrefix = ' ';
scanf_s(" %c", &itemPrefix, 1);
if (isItemExist(itemPrefixes, itemPrefix) == 1) {
printf("Error Item already exist");
continue;
}
else {
itemPrefixes[chosenFruitItem] = itemPrefix;

printf("Enter price for item (%c): ", itemPrefix);
scanf_s("%d", &itemPrices[chosenFruitItem]);
chosenFruitItem++;

}




}

displayMenu(itemPrefixes, itemPrices, n);

printf("\n**CUSTOMER PANEL***");
printf("\nWhat is your budget for today?: ");
scanf_s("%d", &budget);

printf("\nPlease enter Item Prefix from the menu to purchase: ");
scanf_s(" %c", &itemPurchased, 1);

if (withinBudget(budget, itemPurchased, itemPrefixes, itemPrices) == 1) {

printf("PURCHASS SUCCESS");
}
else
{
printf("INSUFFICENT BUDGET");
}




}

int isItemExist(char itemPrefixes[], char itemPrefix) {

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

if (itemPrefixes[i] == itemPrefix) {
return 1;
}
}

return 0;


}

void displayMenu(char itemPrefixes[], int itemPrices[], int n) {

printf("\n*** ShopMenu ***");
printf("\nItem: \t Price: ");

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

printf("\n%c:\t %d", itemPrefixes[i], itemPrices[i]);

}}

int withinBudget(int budget, char itemPurchased, char itemPrefixes[], int itemPrices[]) {

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

if (itemPurchased == itemPrefixes[i] && itemPrices[i] < budget)
{
return 1;
}

return 0;

}




}
```

the output:

[image]

Comment: Sulekha, posting sample input, output seen and output expected would help.

Comment: il try to add that in now

Comment: Best to post text as text and not as a picture.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica to be honest, i dont know what exactly you want me to do

Comment: Compiler warning: 'withinBudget': not all control paths return a value. You have `return 0` in the wrong place, as would have been immediately obvious with properly formatted code ;). I think the logic might need attention too.

Comment: @WeatherVane  I'm new to programming so please can you elaborate on that?

Comment: The loop never completes. In the first iteration it either returns 0 or 1. So only the first array element is tested. It never reaches the end of the function (where the return value is missing).

Comment: so i need a loop inside a loop in order to test the other condition i had? @WeatherVane

Comment: No, you need to return from the loop when you can't afford an item, but wait till the end of the loop to return otherwise, after checking all the elements.

Comment: @WeatherVane shoot, I just realized what you meant, i mistakenly placed the return 0 inside the for loop.

Comment: So, format the code indention properly. It might seem like a chore, but it will save you a great deal of time in the long run.

Comment: @WeatherVane For sure!. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Please ident your code. Either simplest mistakes could go unnoticed because of this.

[Here](https://codebeautify.org/c-formatter-beautifier) you have an auto one.

After doing this to your code, here's the last function:

```
int withinBudget(int budget, char itemPurchased, char itemPrefixes[], int itemPrices[]) {

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

    if (itemPurchased == itemPrefixes[i] && itemPrices[i] < budget) {
      return 1;
    }

    return 0;

  }

}
```

As you can see, `return 0` is inside loop, it's working only if `itemPurchased == itemPrefixes[0] && itemPrices[0] < budget` as `i` will never be incremented.

So your function should be:

```
int withinBudget(int budget, char itemPurchased, char itemPrefixes[], int itemPrices[]) {

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

    if (itemPurchased == itemPrefixes[i] && itemPrices[i] < budget) {
      return 1;
    }
  }

  return 0;

}
```